# How to access a view's width and height in BindingAdapter?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using Android databinding and a **BindingAdapter** to bind an ImageView's bitmap to a bitmap that I load.

```
@BindingAdapter("imageName")
public void bind(ImageView imageView, String imageName) {
   ...
   int width = imageView.getWidth();
   int height = imageView.getHeight();
   ...
}
```

Both `width` and `height` are zero and I understand from my research and the numerous SO posts that I'm probably calling these methods too early and the layout is not drawn yet.

But I can't really move the code to another method when I want to use the BindingAdapter. Is there another way to get the measurements of the view or to postpone the binding process?

Comment: Just add some delay, and then recheck it

Comment: Have you tried imageView.post( ... )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this

```java
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            int width = imageView.getWidth();
            int height = imageView.getHeight();
        }
});
```

this is better than adding delay, it run when you view drawn and remove listener after so no memorylake.

Comment: Thank you, that feels way better than a delay. Just as an addition: i had to add this listener on the ViewTreeObserver like so `imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(...)`

Comment: @JanaFlauschata Yeah, you are right a just forget it and answer edited now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this thing:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageName")
public void bind(ImageView imageView, String imageName) {
    imageView.post(() -> {
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
    });
}
```